# Response not coming properly from spring mvc to angular js using ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and angular js for application in respective backend and frontend. I am using ngresource for the http calls. But in response I am not able to the get the response properly.

**test.js**

```
angular.module('app').factory("testService",

    function($resource) {
        return {
            getdata: $resource('/setupdata',{},
              {
                'save' : {
                method:'POST'
            }
            })  };
    });
    angular.module('app').controller('testController',function($scope, $http,testService) {
    var init = function(){
    testService.getdata.get(function(response) {
    //in response age,height etc is there
    //if I put alert I am getting[Object,Object] and If I put JSON.stringify(data) all the parameters are appearing like age , height etc,If I check with data.age, data.height a blank braces is coming {}.
    } 
    init();
});
```

I am passing Object from my spring MVC. But, I am not getting the response.

Comment: you should use `alert(JSON.stringify(response))`

Comment: If I use I am able to see all my parameters but when I do alert(data.age) undefined is coming.

Comment: put debugger in the code and open web console on your browser..and look at value what it is

Answer (score 0):

The `$resource.get()` expects a query parameters object as the first parameter:

```
testService.getdata.get({ id: 12 }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Or multiple:

```
testService.getdata.query({}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I using post method in spring mvc how come .get will work for post??